# What is the probability distribution (Moran Process where the other colour is always removed)

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, polya-urn-model

### The Problem

Suppose there are $H$ balls in a jar, with $X_i(0)$ white balls and $H-X_i(0)$ blacks balls. At each step, we randomly choose a ball from the jar. If a white ball is chosen, we replace it an *additional* white ball and remove a black ball. If a black ball is chosen, we simply put it back in, with no replacement. Thus, the number of balls is always $H$. We assume that the process never terminates: we keep adding extra white balls even when there are no black balls left. The number of white balls increase exponentially per step when there are black balls (see end of post); once there are only white balls, the growth is linear. This way, we can also consider what happens for arbitrarily large numbers of steps without worrying about stopping at the correct step.

**Notation**

Denote by $X_i(k)$ the number of white balls at the $k$th step, so initially there are $X_i(0)=i$ balls. That is,

- $k$ is the number of steps,
- $i$ is the number of white balls *initially*,
- Finally, $X_i(k)$ is the number of white balls after $k$ steps, for $i$ initially white balls.

**Goal**

I am trying to calculate/identify the following probability distribution (next paragraph), or even $E[X^2]$ at each step, to ultimately determine the variance (I have derived $E[X]$ as shown later).

---

### What I know

A similar question is asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598232/dynamics-of-an-urn-with-additional-replacement-of-one-colour-and-removal-of-the), but it is only concerned with the number of iterations till there are only white balls. There are a few highly relevant wiki articles, but none have the exact process I am looking for:

- The [Polya Distribution Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_urn_model) outlines that

> there are variants of the Moran model that insist that the ball removed from the urn be a different ball from one originally sampled in that step

but I cannot find the relevant resource. Even looking through the page for [Moran Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moran_process#Selection), I didn't find a section where the opposite allele is always removed.

### An Attempt

**Expected value:**

At any step, we have

$$E[X_i(k+1)]= (X_i(k)+1)\cdot \frac{X_i(k)}{H} + X_i(k) \cdot \frac{H-X_i(k)}{H}$$
Solving the recursive equation we get
$$ E[X_i(k)] = X_i(0)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{H} \right)^k$$

until $X_i(k) \geq H$. This way, I have avoided having to find the probability distribution. However, I can't find a way to apply similar logic for $E[X_i(k)^2]$.

Comment: You may have confused $H$ and $N$ and I am not totally clear what you are looking for.  Is it the distribution of $X_i$ or the variance of $X_i$, the number of white balls after $i$ steps?  When all the balls are white, presumably future draws make no difference as there are no black balls to replace

Comment: @Henry Yes I have, that is supposed to be H, not N. My apologies. 

I suppose the notation is pretty confusing, might be bad choice. To clarify, $k$ is the number of steps, $i$ is the number of *initial* white balls - so $E[X_1(2)]$ is the number of white balls after 2 steps, if we had 1 white ball to start with.

Finally, I am looking for the variance in the number of white balls at $k$ steps.

Comment: @Henry The termination is interesting if we keep adding extra white balls even when there are no black balls left. The number of white balls increase exponentially per step when there are black balls; once there are only white balls, the growth is linear. This way, we can also consider $X_1(500), H=100$, and get $E[X_1](500) = 137.18$, for example.

Comment: This is not clear.  Please edit your original post for clarity, don't leave critical information for the comments.  What is $X$? What do you do when there are no black balls left?  Does that simply end the game?

Comment: Guessing that $X$ is the number of trials until all the black balls are gone, I would think that this could best be analyzed via states (labelled according to how many black balls are left).  But perhaps you meant something entirely different.

Comment: @lulu I am so sorry that the notation is so confusing! I have added extra clarification in the post, if that helps. But no, $X$ is a function of the number of white balls, with $i$ as the initial number of white balls, and $k$ as the number of steps since start. Hence, $X_i(k)$

Comment: Nowhere, even in the post-edit version, is $X$ defined.  I'm sure your intent is clear to you, but I don't think it will be clear to any readers.  If you are going to refer to $X$ (especially as the target of the main question), you should define it clearly and unambiguously.

Comment: @lulu I have added a notation and goal section. Would you reckon that suffices?

Comment: I suggest editing the post to clean up the notation.  You introduce $X_0$, which I'm guessing you later redefine to just be $i$, right?  In any case, the subscript in $X_0$ doesn't mean $"0"$, though the subscript in $X_i$ does mean $"i"$ elsewhere.   And, still, you use $X$ without defining it.  I am guessing from your comments that you intend it to refer to some $X_i(t)$ without specifying either $i$ or $t$, right?   Anyway, I think it could all be cleaned up a lot.

Comment: In any case:  I'd have thought that indicator variables worked here (though the fact that the game continues with no black balls might mess that up).  Letting $Y_i$ denote the indicator variable for the presence of the $i^{th}$ black ball then you are interested in $(\sum Y_i)^2=\sum Y_i+\sum_{i\neq j} Y_iY_j$ and that doesn't look hard to analyze.  Again, I have not thought through how this plays out once you are done with the black balls.